# Freeradius Proxy Setting and Strongswan

Tags: vpn, freeradius, radius

I have a radius server like Freeradius . My radius server does not support EAP.
Ikev2 (Strongswan) project uses EAP-radius for authentications IKev2 Clients.

IKev2 (Strongswan) works fine with Freeradius for authentiction. But when Ikev2 sends request to my radius server, it receives access-accept but can not start EAP .

My radius server can understand mschap1, mschap2 , chap , pap.
I have read document about proxy in Freeradius and I know Freeradius can send radius to other server with Proxy setting .

- How can I config proxy in Freeradius to send just authentication (username and password) to my radius server and after receives access-accept, the remaining scenarios should be completed by Freeradius and Ikev2 clients able to connect ?

Is it possible?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your servers are set up, because you didn't post any of the config files. So it will be impossible for me to suggest a solution.

If i were you, I'd take a look at a ikev2+radius tutorial like this one. [IKEV2 Radius guide](https://draculaservers.com/tutorials/ikev2-vpn-strongswan-letsencrypt/)